# Count number of non-empty fields in Excel VB array's column

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I currently read a 2-dimensional range into an Excel VBA array like so:

```
Set Ws = Sheet1
Ws.Activate

LastRow = Ws.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
LastCol = Ws.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column

ReDim elements(0 To LastRow - 2, 0 To LastCol - 2)
elements = Ws.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
```

The range is 25 rows by 11 columns. However, not all cells in the range have values so some of the values in the array are 'empty'.

- col A has 25 items
- col B has 16
- col K has 12...

I need to loop through this array and create a second array, which will be a **"Cartesian product" of the values from the first one**. In order to determine how many times I need to loop I need to figure out how many items there are in each of the arrays columns ("dimensions"?).

Here is an attempt of my loop:

```
Row = 0

For i = 1 To 25  'numElements in column 1
 For j = 1 To 3    'numElements in column 6           
  For k = 1 To 5    'numElements in column 7
   For l = 1 To 14    'numElements in column 8
    For m = 1 To 6     'numElements in column 10
     For n = 1 To 12     'numElements in column 11

      cartesian(Row, 0) = elements(i, 0)
      cartesian(Row, 1) = elements(i, 1)
      cartesian(Row, 2) = elements(i, 2)
      cartesian(Row, 3) = elements(i, 3)
      cartesian(Row, 4) = elements(i, 4)
      cartesian(Row, 5) = elements(j, 5)
      cartesian(Row, 6) = elements(k, 6)
      cartesian(Row, 7) = elements(l, 7)
      cartesian(Row, 8) = elements(l, 8)
      cartesian(Row, 9) = elements(m, 9)
      cartesian(Row, 10) = elements(n, 10)

       Row = Row + 1
     Next n         
    Next m
   Next l
  Next k
 Next j
Next i
```

Any help appreciated :)

**EDIT 1:**

This is the range that I read into array1:

```
Austria  sem  jan
Belgium  gdn  feb
France        mar
US            apr
              may
              jun
```

I need to be able to count how many "items" there are in column 1, column 2 and column 3 in order to multiply them. That way I will know how big I need to ReDim second array.

This is what I need in the array 2 and to finally write back into another sheet:

```
Austria  sem    jan
Austria  sem    feb
Austria  sem    mar
Austria  sem    apr
Austria  sem    may
Austria  sem    jun
Austria  gdn    jan
Austria  gdn    feb
Austria  gdn    mar
Austria  gdn    apr
Austria  gdn    may
Austria  gdn    jun
Belgium  sem    jan
Belgium  sem    feb
Belgium  sem    mar
Belgium  sem    apr
Belgium  sem    may
Belgium  sem    jun
Belgium  gdn    jan
Belgium  gdn    feb
Belgium  gdn    mar
Belgium  gdn    apr
Belgium  gdn    may
Belgium  gdn    jun
```

etc.

Comment: I think this may be overthinking it.  What's your goal, to just find the cells that are empty, in a range?  So, for columns 1, 6,7,8,10, and 11, you are wanting to find the empty cells?

Comment: Or Alex just want to combine the "non empty" values of columns 2 to 11 with the values of column 1?

Comment: I also don't get it... going for *Cartesian product* but there are no calculations... it's just a copy of the first range (just the values are shuffled). So what are the different sets to start with? each row? but having n sets also provides a n-dimensional output... I'm confused :/

Comment: Kellsens - BINGO! :) This is so difficult to explain wothout an example spreadsheet. Yes, I need to "combine" all the non empty values (they are all strings) from ALL the columns "with each other" (or as you have put it - with column one. So first, I loop through the last column. Then I increment second to last +1 and loop through the last again. I continue doing this until all the values from all the columns have been "combined". 25 cells colA x 3 cells colF x 5 cells colG x .... Equals about 300.000 rows that go into new range.

Comment: so you want every possible combination of all columns (having one value from each column)... like 1,2,3 / a,b / 9,8,7 would be 1a9, 1a8, 1a7, 1b9, 1b8, 1b7, 2a9, 2a8, 2a7, 2b9, 2b8, 2b7.... did I got this correct?

Comment: Dirk, that is correct! every possible combination odlf these strings from the first range. Once I create this "cartesian product" as I call it - I the use it to write certain values in adjacent columns. But that part is under control; it's these combinations that I'm tring to improve. It was real slow because there are a lot of rows

Answer (score 1):

This should do it like you need it in a decent amount of time... still will take some time for ~300k entries:

```
Option Explicit

Sub getMyList()

  'set input
  Dim inputVal As Variant

  'get input values
  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    inputVal = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Cells.Find("*", , , , 1, 2).Row, .Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column)).Value
  End With

  'set count array
  Dim xCounts() As Variant
  ReDim xCounts(1 To UBound(inputVal, 2))

  Dim i As Long, j As Long
  For i = 1 To UBound(xCounts)
    j = 1
    While inputVal(j, i) <> "" And j < UBound(inputVal)
      j = j + 1
    Wend
    'xCounts(i) = j - 1 'will skip last value if it is at the last row
    xCounts(i) = j + (inputVal(j, i) = "") 'new one will work as wanted
  Next

  'set output sizes
  Dim outVal() As Variant
  ReDim outVal(1 To Application.Product(xCounts), 1 To UBound(xCounts))

  'runner sets
  Dim colRunner As Long, rowRunner As Long, copyRunner As Long
  Dim itemRep As Long, listRep As Long

  For colRunner = 1 To UBound(xCounts)

    rowRunner = 1
    itemRep = 1
    listRep = 1

    'repeat whole list
    For i = 1 To colRunner - 1
      listRep = listRep * xCounts(i)
    Next

    'repeat each item
    For i = colRunner + 1 To UBound(xCounts)
      itemRep = itemRep * xCounts(i)
    Next

    'run the list for output
    copyRunner = 1
    For i = 1 To listRep
      For copyRunner = 1 To xCounts(colRunner)
        For j = 1 To itemRep

          outVal(rowRunner, colRunner) = inputVal(copyRunner, colRunner)
          rowRunner = rowRunner + 1

        Next
      Next
    Next
  Next

  'output everything
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(outVal), UBound(outVal, 2)).Value = outVal

End Sub
```

The code should be easy to read (there is no real magic inside) :P

However, if any questions are left, just ask :)

**EDIT**

The `xCounter` simply hold the counts of all items for each column because this numbers are used lots of times.
For clarification: Let's assume you have a list like this:

```
A B C D E
1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2
3   3 3 3
4   4 4
5   5 5
6   6 6
7     7
8
```

(Used numbers for easy counting,  also works with any strings)
xCounter will now be `{8,2,6,7,3}`. Now if you want to write down the column C then you need to know how many times each item needs to be repeated. This can be calculated by multiplying the counts of all columns which come later. For this case it would be `7 * 3 = 21` times. Also, you need to know how many items are in the list to loop through which will be `6`. Then the whole list also needs to repeat itself which can be calculated by multiplying all counts of rows which are in front of it. That would be `8 * 2 = 16` times. This way also the 3 inner `For ... Next` loops are build up. `ListRepeat(EachItem(ItemRepeat))`.
To know which line in the output array is to be written you need a simple up counting value which is the `RowCounter`. Doing this directly into the sheet you would use a range which simply offsets one row down every time a value is written in a cell.
By this system you do every column completely seperated from the others because all you need are the products of the item counts of the leading and following columns (for which we have xCounter). Still we need to do this for each column so the outer loop is the column (colRunner).
Simply for not getting confused by having 4 loops using `i, j, k, l` inside each other I renamed the "runner" for the rows in the `outVal` to `rowRunner` and the one for the columns to `colRunner`. Having the upper and lower limits for the repeats directly set in front of the inner loops, I stayed with `i` and `j`. (Also they are not used for anything in that loops, they simply ensure the repeats by doing the same action mutiple times)

If I missed something or other questions pop up, just do it as it is always the right thing to do: ask. ;)

Comment: I like the way you've done this (I was thinking of a different way but probably not as good). One thing I noticed was it skips 'jun' in the last column - suggest something like     For j = 1 To UBound(inputVal)
    If inputVal(j, i) = "" Then Exit For
    Next j  in set count array code.

Comment: @TomSharpe changed `xCounts(i) = j - 1` to `xCounts(i) = j + (inputVal(j, i) = "")`. should work now :)

Comment: Dirk, THANKS for the huge effort I really appreciate it! Here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/astrbac/vj1atc82) is how I "adjusted" it a bit to my style (declarations at the top). I am however, struggling a bit with understanding: you first create an array of elements to combine. In the end you create an array to write back to the sheet. I don't however understand whz the xCount array and what does the rowRunner and colRunner do? Many thanks for clariffications in advance!

Comment: @AlexStarbuck Edited the answer to explain my solution a bit better (hopefully in an understandable way)